# What is the best way to pass `this` to a supplier?

Tags: java, function, lambda

In Java 8+ we have `Function.identity()` which will return back the input object - equivalent to `t -> t`

Is there a predefined function or another way that returns `this` - equivalent to `() -> this`? If so, does it provide a benefit? (for example, saved allocations and anonymous class definitions)

**Edit**

Perhaps this question deserves some expansion. A specific case I am looking at is `java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture#completeAsync(java.util.function.Supplier<? extends T>)`

I have a class that holds a value and a future that will eventually resolve, but not until another component is ready. I don't want to complete it with `future.complete(...)` because the calling thread would have to perform any chained actions.

```java
class Thing<T> {
    final T value;
    final CompletableFuture<T> future;

    Thing<T> self() {
        return this;
    }

    void reject() {
        future.cancel(false);
    }

    void complete() {
        // Does allocating the lambda here have a cost?
        future.complete(() -> this);
        // Does passing a method reference avoid one?
        future.complete(this::self);
    }
}
```

Comment: No, how could you even implement that?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Perhaps the example I added helps clarify the question

Comment: No, it doesn't exist and you don't need it. Even `Function.identity()` is of questionable value.

Comment: @shmosel Can you explain why it's of questionable value?

Comment: What's the point? `t -> t` is more concise and speaks for itself.

Comment: There is no way to avoid costs equivalent to those incurred by `() -> this`.  As a result, you might as well just do that.

Answer (score 0):

From outside: If you have an object `o` and want to get something like `o.getThis()` and expect the refernce to `o`as a result, why not use `o` directly?

From inside: As soon as you are running code within `o`, it can reference other fields or methods by indicating `this.otherField`. An alternative would be to reference something inherited, which could end up in `super.otherField`.

So I do not see any benefit here to have one more function.

Comment: Perhaps the example I added helps clarify the question